# SQL Server 2017 - "SQL Server Assertion:" Error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I'm encountering a scenario very similar to this:

[SQL 2016 SQL Server Assertion: File: <pageref.cpp>, line=951 Failed Assertion](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/144889/sql-2016-sql-server-assertion-file-pageref-cpp-line-951-failed-assertion)

With more or less the same error text:

> SQL Server Assertion: File: <pageref.cpp>, line=1496 Failed Assertion
> = 'IS_OFF (BUF_MINLOGGED, m_buf->bstat) || pageModifyType != PageModifyType_Contents || GetPagePtr ()->IsTextPage ()'. This error
> may be timing-related. If the error persists after rerunning the
> statement, use DBCC CHECKDB to check the database for structural
> integrity, or restart the server to ensure in-memory data structures
> are not corrupted.

I found a KB that says that it fixes this issue:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb3205964-fix-an-assertion-occurs-when-you-bulk-insert-data-into-a-table-from-multiple-connections-in-sql-server-2016-3fbe6f26-4cbe-43bb-9ddf-3c302fa5562f

Problem is, that fix is for 201**6**, not 201**7**.  This instance is running 2017 CU22-GDR (KB4583457 - 14.0.3370.1), so it's on the latest GDR CU as of this writing.

I work for a managed service provider.  I'm not privy to what queries are being run, nor can I make any alterations to any queries, so I can't provide any insight there.

Anyone know what could cause this error in 2017?  Other than asking the client to investigate any "bulk insert data into a table from multiple connections" operations?

Comment: At least one cause (hard to say if it's the same given not knowing what's going on per your statement) was fixed in CU21 which is already applied unless it regressed. However, per the "so it's not lacking any updates" statement, CU22 GDR is almost a year old, the latest is currently CU27 though I didn't see anything specifically for the issue at hand in CU23-27.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/kb4567166-fix-assertion-failure-occurs-when-you-try-to-insert-record-into-a-page-in-fully-logged-mode-in-sql-server-2017-and-2019-3dbe205c-3a6f-f691-1f6c-8841c28423d0

Comment: @SeanGallardy-MostlyRetired OP is on the GDR train which only contains security fixes, so you need to check all CUs from the beginning

Comment: @Charlieface see my comment on your answer, the OP is on the CU train (22 w/security).

Comment: @SeanGallardy-MostlyRetired I could have articulated the "not lacking any updates" statement better.  I was trying to say that it isn't all the way back on RTM.  CU22 GDR is the latest GDR patch, so maybe that's why it's still on that.  I'll edit the question to better reflect what I was trying to articulate.